# How to combine date portion of one date and combine it with time portion of another date

Tags: javascript, date, datetime, date-fns

I have the following date with time info within my JavaScript app:

```
"startDate": "2021-05-25T09:50:40.603Z"
"startTime": "2021-05-12T11:52:40.603Z"
```

What I need to achieve is to create a new variable that takes the date portion only of "startDate" and combine it with the time portion of "startTime", i.e.

```
2021-05-25 + T11:52:40.603Z = 2021-05-25T11:52:40.603Z
```

I was looking at using date-fns format to perform the above split but unsure how to combine it again as I need to ensure that the new combined date and time is still a JavaScript date object as above.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming your dates are in the ISO format and need another ISO date string as the result:

```js
function start (date, time) {
    return `${date.split("T")[0]}T${time.split("T")[1]}`;
}

console.log(start("2021-05-25T09:50:40.603Z", "2021-05-12T11:52:40.603Z"));
```

In the ISO format, the date is separated from the time using the letter `T` (for "time"). My function splits both dates at that point. For the date, we use `[0]` (before T) and the time is `[1]` (after the T). The `Z` (Zulu) at the end stands for Zulu Time which is the same as UTC. More about this format on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601).

When storing dates and times in JavaScript, I would highly recommend using UNIX timestamps, which is a number representing the milliseconds past after the beginning of the UNIX epoch (Jan 1 1970). These timestamps can easily be converted to date objects in most programming languages and platforms. Here is the same function, but using UNIX timestamps and the JavaScript date object.

```js
function start (date, time) {
  return new Date(`${new Date(date).toDateString()} ${new Date(time).toTimeString()}`)
}

console.log(start(1621936240603, 1620820360603));
// this function will also recognise strings
console.log(start("25 May 2020", "Feb 13 2019 9:00 AM UTC"));
```

Answer (score 2):

You can just use the Date object:

```js
const target = new Date("2021-05-25T09:50:40.603Z")
const startTime = new Date("2021-05-12T11:52:40.603Z")

target.setHours(startTime.getHours())
target.setMinutes(startTime.getMinutes())
target.setSeconds(startTime.getSeconds())
target.setMilliseconds(startTime.getMilliseconds())
console.log(target)
```

Or by manupulating the strings, you can do it so:

```
const startDate = "2021-05-25T09:50:40.603Z";
const startTime = "2021-05-12T11:52:40.603Z";
console.log(`${startDate.substr(0,11)}${startTime.substr(11)}`)
```